# Web Font Performance - Boot.getFont

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have read the Article [here](http://www.artzstudio.com/2012/02/) about the Web Font Performance and the Developer "**arztstudio**" made a Font Loader in JavaScript called [Boot.getFont](http://www.artzstudio.com/2012/02/).

Github: https://github.com/artzstudio/Boot

Well, i did not test it but his Diagram show that his Loader is after System Fonts placed.

I would be happy if you can share your knowledge and post some Comments about Web Font Performance.

Comment: Sorry, closing as not constructive. Is there an actual question that you have?

Comment: Technical Question not.. Just was asking the knowledge of People what they know about Web Font Performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great articles about Web Font performance on the [Google Developers website.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization?hl=en)

One of my favourite articles about Web Fonts and performance is also on the Filament Group website and is entitled "[How we use web fonts responsibly, or, avoiding a @font-face-palm](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html)", I recommend having a read.

If you are looking to asynchronously load your Web Fonts, check out this [Github repo](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader). It is a Web Font loader that gives you added control when using linked fonts via @font-face.

And finally, if you are interested in a list of web performance articles, check out this site [deanhume.github.io/typography](http://deanhume.github.io/typography/font-performance.html). I try and update it regularly!